# Vector map - Multiple local sources with Mapbox-GL

Tags: openstreetmap, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl, osm2vectortiles

I'm building a web map using Mapbox-GL (renderer) and OSM2Vectortiles (vector map tiles).

- Since the OpenStreetMap's data are insufficient in my country, I've used QGIS and Satelite images to add some roads, POIs,... and converted to vector tiles (PBF files).
- It's quite difficult and time-consuming to merge my data with OSM, and then convert the whole complex things again.
- I know that Mapbox support multiple sources, but I only found examples where the sources coming from Mapbox. I'd like to serve the tiles without Mapbox's cloud services.

Is it possible to use multiple sources (OSM2Vectortiles + My rendered tiles) with Mapbox-GL-js?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why can't you just add the data to OpenStreetMap in the first place?

Comment: Because me and my team want a total control on what we added. We want the added data to be displayed immediately without approval from OSM.

Comment: There's no such thing as "approval from OSM". Once you upload your changes, they will be immediately available worldwide.

Comment: wow thanks! I'll try editing OSM maps directly. Hopefully OSM2Vectortiles will update their vector tiles quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily combine multiple tiles in your JSON GL style.

Just define more identifiers in the `sources` section and point them to different tiles (http or mbtiles).

```
"sources": {
  "osm2vectortiles": {
    "type": "vector",
    "url": "https://osm2vectortiles.tileserver.com/v2.json"
  },
  "naturalearth": {
    "type": "vector",
    "maxzoom": 7,
    "tiles": [
       "http://naturalearthtiles.org/tiles/natural_earth.vector/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
    ]
  }
},
```

This is supported in all MapBox SDKs (JavaScript / Android / iOS / ..)

Our TileServer-GL will also rasterize such styles into raster tiles and give you sample viewers out of the box for such JSON style. See:
http://blog.klokantech.com/2016/08/tileserver-gl-maps-with-gl-json-styles.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This is extremely helpful. Exactly what I wanted :)